# Rest clients do not unzip automatically gzipped responses

Tags: json, rest, http, gzip

I compressed my JSON Headers like following :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream( out );
gzip.write( responseBody.encodePrettily().getBytes( "UTF-8" ) );
gzip.close();
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
String response = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( bytes );
```

And I send this response from the server.
On any browser, the response is automatically unzipped and the json data is retrieved. But when sending a GET request on Postman, Insomnia or RestClient (Mozilla Addon), I get the encoded gzip instead of the json data:

```
H4sIAAAAAAAAAM2POwvCMBSF90L/wyVzB9tmcnZxcLFuIiE0VwikD/IQpOS/20RL1cGt0vWcw/3uN6QJANFonLIE...
```

How can I make get it unzipped ? I tried with several Rest Clients and none of them unzips it like a browser does.

I found nowhere an answer to this and I'm starting feeling hopeless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved ! Actually it was not necessary to compress the responses manually like I have shown in my question because we're using Vert.X.

Vert.X provides a clever Option to be set in HttpServerOptions in order to do the compression automatically whenever it is possible (i.e. client is supporting compression). Postman and any other REST Client (i.e. browser or whatever) gets the zipped response and automatically unzip it !

I wasted a lot of time but at least learnt something useful. That's why I wanted to share it with you.

If you're using Vert.X, this line of code will do the work for you :

`HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions().setCompressionSupported( true );`

Then simply use this HttpServerOptions instance when creating your HttpServer :

`HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer( options );`

PS: You can verify that the compression really happened when you check the response headers returned by your client. You'll find `content-encoding : gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a Content-Coding response header field, indicating "gzip" (see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#data.encoding)

Comment: I did it but it didn't help. I even added a Transfer-Coding in the header. I always get :
`content-coding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
transfer-coding: gzip
content-encoding: gzip
transfer-encoding: chunked` and the response body as I wrote above.

Comment: because I need to unzip them in the tests. So they need to be Base64 encoded in order to retrieve a valid String instead of a binary like e.g. �]��
�0E�B��������Cu �yB MC�"���yZ���˽K���1Yp�;,��l ...

Comment: Well, they are not supposed to be base64 encoded. HTTP response bodies can carry binaries just fine. It's no surprise when standard clients give up on that.

Comment: Even when I do not base64 encode it, I still get the same result : ��������]��
�0E�B��������Cu �yB MC�"���yZ���˽K����1Yp�;,��l���){%E)��%kw_A��x�=�uɄ���PI+�� ... even with content-coding header set to gzip.
There seem to be no solution for this. So I add a request header `Accept-Encoding : json` in Postman and I verify in my code before compressing. If the header is set I do not compress. It's not perfect but better than it was.

Comment: There is no content-coding "json". Did you perhaps mean *Content-Type*????

FWIW, whether a given HTTP client lib automatically unwraps content codings usually is a configuration question - the caller might have to do it itself.

Comment: I never wrote a content-coding: json. I know there is no such thing. Hmm now my problem seems to be that configuration issue. I will keep the workaround I implemented until I get a better solution.

Comment: Accept-Coding is for content codings. And there is no such content coding.